# How to pass DOM Document created using Axiom to evaluate XPath in Psychopath processor

Tags: java, dom, xpath, axiom

Currently Psychopath Xpath processor uses XercesLoader class to load bytestream and create org.w3c.dom.Document and it can be passed to evaluate the Xpath.

```
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream("resources/test.xml");
 DOMLoader loader = new XercesLoader(); 
 Document doc = loader.load(is);
```

I created org.w3c.dom.Document using axiom and passed it to Psychopath.

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("resources/test.xml");

    OMMetaFactory omMetaFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.FEATURE_DOM);
    OMFactory omFac = omMetaFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMXMLParserWrapper wrapper = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(omFac, is) ;
    Document doc = (Document) wrapper.getDocument();
```

But when passing doc2 it gives the error

> Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: The implementation does not support the requested type of object or operation. 
>       at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.DOMUtil.newDOMException(DOMUtil.java:82)
>       at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.NodeImpl.compareDocumentPosition(NodeImpl.java:212)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.types.NodeType.compare_node(NodeType.java:219)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.types.NodeType.access$0(NodeType.java:207)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.types.NodeType$1.compare(NodeType.java:64)
>       at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:545)
>       at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:342)
>       at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.types.NodeType.linarize(NodeType.java:415)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.DefaultEvaluator.do_step(DefaultEvaluator.java:1165)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.DefaultEvaluator.visit(DefaultEvaluator.java:1249)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.ast.XPathExpr.accept(XPathExpr.java:43)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.DefaultEvaluator.do_expr(DefaultEvaluator.java:337)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.DefaultEvaluator.visit(DefaultEvaluator.java:366)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.ast.XPath.accept(XPath.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.DefaultEvaluator.evaluate2(DefaultEvaluator.java:325)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.ast.XPath.evaluate(XPath.java:131)
>       at psychopath.main(psychopath.java:85)

Needs an explanation. How to pass the DOM Document instance made using axiom to Psychopath to evaluate XPath?

Comment: Which statement exactly gives the error you have shown?

Comment: You should post the complete stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is simple: Axiom's DOM implementation doesn't implement the `compareDocumentPosition` method (defined by DOM 3).